# Trying to edit the Container on Product Pages

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, containers, html

I'm currently trying to edit the div.container on this page: http://honestabe.ca/ininkk/product/cant-recycle-wasted-time/

I'd like for the product picture to be large within the container, but also for there to be enough space for the sidebar widgets (cart & search bar).

This is the current code I am using in my custom CSS and I would like for the solution to apply to only the product pages that currently exist and will be created in the future.

```css
.content-left.page-with-sidebar.col-sm-8.col-md-9.col-lg-8 {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 400px;
}
.content-right.col-sm-4.col-md-3.col-lg-3.col-lg-offset-1 {
  margin: 0px;
}
.single.single-product.row {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 600px;
}
.single.single-product.postid-49.container {
  width: 1600px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

If anyone can help, that'd be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is awesome for applying CSS to certain pages, page types, post types, etc. It adds a class to the body depending on what it is. Here's a listing of the linked page's body classes:

`<body class="single single-product postid-49 woocommerce woocommerce-page wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-4.11.2 vc_responsive">`

If you'd like all of that stuff to only apply to `product` pages, I suggest you modify the given CSS to this:

```
body.product .content-left.page-with-sidebar.col-sm-8.col-md-9.col-lg-8{
width: 1200px;
height: 400px;}

body.product .content-right.col-sm-4.col-md-3.col-lg-3.col-lg-offset-1{
margin: 0px;}

body.product .single.single-product.row{
width: 1600px;
height: 600px;}

body.product .single.single-product.postid-49.container{
width: 1600px;
margin: 20px;}
```

However, I must warn you- after looking at these CSS declarations you have, it looks like you may have trouble.

**For example, the class** `.postid-49` **only applies to one product; not all of them.**

Also, I think you're going to have trouble with responsiveness of the website if that's any particular goal.

Comment: If you can check it now, you'll see that I used the code you gave me, but in reality, I'm only trying to edit the product pages so that the single product image is larger than the current size. I was wondering if there was any way of doing that? The options given in the woocommerce settings didn't work so CSS is the only way to go. It's the reason why I was messing with the containers. Thank you, however, for taking the time to answer my question, I really do appreciate the help!

Comment: Your comment leads me to believe you've not understood my posted answer, or haven't read it thoroughly enough.